Flyway with Apache Ignite
Can someone tell me how to integrate Flyway with Apache Ignite. I found maven dependency in Flyway docs, but it can't find 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'.
What can be a reasone for this and how I can fix it?
Maybe there is more convinient way to do migration.
The main idea is to sql scripts on application starts if they have not been applied recentrly.
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-ignite</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

Exception in thread "main" org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to check whether schema "PUBLIC" exists
----------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 1001
Message    : Failed to validate query. From line 1, column 22 to line 1, column 48: Object 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' not found

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Schema.exists(Schema.java:57)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:89)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:418)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.lambda$migrate$0(Flyway.java:162)
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:210)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:151)
    at com.soramaki.fna.imbe.IMBeApplication.main(IMBeApplication.java:20)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate query. From line 1, column 22 to line 1, column 48: Object 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' not found
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:1010)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:234)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinPreparedStatement.executeWithArguments(JdbcThinPreparedStatement.java:252)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcThinPreparedStatement.java:78)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:111)
    at org.flywaydb.community.database.ignite.thin.IgniteThinSchema.doExists(IgniteThinSchema.java:48)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Schema.exists(Schema.java:55)
    ... 6 more


Ignite hasn't had the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for some time. Most of the same information is in the SYS schema, but using it would require some code changes in Flyway.

Thanks, is there any other way to do migration of caches created on application startup? For example, I have Client Node that connects to the K8s Ignite Cluster (2 Server Nodes) and creates Cache, it works fine, but then I remove/change one field in this Cache and restart Client Node it will fail on trying to adjust already existing Cache. How can I solve this, maybe there are some best practises, or other migration tools?
